# Python - List concatenate

Tags: python, list

I have two lists and I want to create one list containing its data.

```
ls1 = ["1","2","3","4"]

ls2 = ["4","3","2","1"]
```

The answer I am looking for is of this form....

```
ls3 = ["1-4","2-3","3-2","4-1"]
```

Is there any possibility of achieving this? Note the minus sign between the numbers.

Comment: Any reason why you're looking to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So @aesthete's answer is right.  I just want to add explanation.

```
>>> ls3 = ['-'.join(x) for x in zip(ls1, ls2)]
['1-4', '2-3', '3-2', '4-1']
```

the `[someaction(x) for x in somelist]` will return a list where each element is `someaction()` performed on the corresponding `x` in `somelist`.  This is called a *list comprehension*.

In this case `somelist` is `zip(ls1,ls2)` which creates `[(ls1[0], ls2[0]), (ls1[1], ls2[1]), ...]`

So `zip(ls1,ls2)` returns `[('1', '4'), ('2', '3'), ('3', '2'), ('4', '1')]`

The `someaction()` is `'-'.join()`  What that does is it takes a iterable sequence of strings and joins them together with the string `'-'` in between.  So you could have done `' to '.join(x)` to get `['1 to 4', '2 to 3', ...]`

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> ls3 = ['-'.join(x) for x in zip(ls1, ls2)]
['1-4', '2-3', '3-2', '4-1']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> [ "{}-{}".format(ls1[x],ls2[x]) for x in range(len(ls1))]
['1-4', '2-3', '3-2', '4-1']
```

using map:

```
>>> map("{}-{}".format,ls1,ls2)
['1-4', '2-3', '3-2', '4-1']
```

using itertools.strmap:

```
>>> list(itertools.starmap("{}-{}".format,zip(ls1,ls2)))
['1-4', '2-3', '3-2', '4-1']
```

Comment: This is creative. `map('{}-{}'.format, ls1, ls2)` would make this idea look really good

Comment: yep this is alo nice `list(itertools.starmap("{}-{}".format,zip(ls1,ls2)))`
['1-4', '2-3', '3-2', '4-1']

Comment: I've never been able to find a good use for `starmap` in my life, i don't think that is a good use either